# Monogame and .fx files?

Tags: mono, monogame

I'm currently following this tutorial but using MonoGame :
http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Terrain_from_file.php
As said in the tutorial, my main goal is to render a terrain from an image file.

There is a .fx provided with the tutorial which I included in my project.

I had some issues using MonoGame to load the bmp file for example and now I managed to load it. The problem comes now from the fx file. MonoDevelop tells this : `The MGX File is Corrupt !`

Here is the original code from the writer of the article :
`effect = Content.Load<Effect> ("effects");`

And here is how I used it with MonoGame :
`effect = Content.Load<Effect> ("effects.fx");`

I am really lost about the usage of the effects file in MonoGame. Is there any good tutorial about this ? Anyway I'm really lost with MonoGame. How come there is no clear tutorials for MonoGame has it is widely used ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your shader .fx to appropriate file format for monogame using 2MGFX tool. You can find the tool inside installed monogame directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0`

How to use:

1. Create a .bat file and write code as shown below:
2. `2MGFX.exe effects.fx effects.mgfxo
   pause`
3. Execute the .bat file

Note that the shader file, .bat file and 2MGFX.exe must be in same directory.

Here is how to use compiled .mgfxo file as effect:

1. Put the effects.mgfxo into Assets\Content folder of your project
2. Load a file as shown below

---

```
Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectNameSpace.Assets.Content.effects.mgfxo");
BinaryReader Reader = new BinaryReader(s);
Effect effect = new Effect(graphics, Reader.ReadBytes((int)Reader.BaseStream.Length));
```

---

If you have problems converting a shader .fx to .mgfxo please leave comments.

Comment: I'm currently using Linux. I tried to recompile the tool "2MGFX" but sadly it didn't seem to work... Any workaround using Linux ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with linux. :(

Comment: Having got this working with your answer (thanks!) I've now added the conversion as a pre-build event in VS.  Also note that the `mgfxo` file needs to have its Build Action set to `EmbeddedResource`.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to follow [Riemers](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/The_effect_file.php) tutorial myself, like you, I struggled with the effects.

I had to make a couple changes to the original effects file before I successfully managed to compile and use it without any exceptions.

Renamed the following:

- vs_2_0 to **vs_4_0**
- ps_2_0 to **ps_4_0**
- POSITION to **SV_POSITION**

Once these changes were made I used the compile tool like following:

> **2MGFX.exe effects.fx effects.mgfxo /Profile:DirectX_11**

Once compiled I moved the mgfxo file into my contents folder and assigned following parameters:

- Build action: Embedded resource
- Copy to output directory: Copy always

It took me a couple of attempts until I managed to use the shader without MonoGame throwing any exceptions at me.

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("Content/effects.mgfxo");
effect = new Effect(GraphicsDevice, bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the 2MGFX tool is optional, you can either use the tool or the Content pipeline, personally I prefer the Content pipeline because it will automatically process the shader file everytime I (re)build the Content project.

How to do this?

1. First: add a MonoGame Content project,
2. Then add the .FX file in this project
3. Set the Content processor to: "MonoGame effect content processor" in properties
4. Then, in your game project *Add a Reference* to this Content project.

And use the shader like so:

```
var myEffect = Content.Load<Effect>("shaderFileNameWithoutExtension");
```

or if you have folders in your content project:

```
var myEffect = Content.Load<Effect>("FolderName\\shaderFileNameWithoutExtension");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing you're working on Linux. Compiling shaders on Linux is a little difficult. In my own projects, I find the following resource especially helpful.

http://www.infinitespace-studios.co.uk/general/monogame-building-fx-shaders-on-a-mac-and-linux/

Following this, you're able to build shaders using the MonoGame Pipeline as normal (provided you have added the pipeline reference).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please describe the example if possible. Link answers are generally not accepted unless retyping the entire page is the only way the idea will get across. If there is a specific thing that needs to be done, please write that in your answer, instead of the link.