# "Incorrect parameter" error in DrawUserPrimitives call

Tags: f#, monogame

I'm getting an unhandled exception with the message `HRESULT: [0x80070057], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_INVALIDARG/Invalid Arguments], Message: The parameter is incorrect.` at the call to `DrawUserPrimitives` in the code below:

```
namespace Game1

open Microsoft.Xna.Framework
open Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics

open System.IO
open System.Reflection

type Game1() as this =
    inherit Game()
    let graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this)
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable effect : Effect
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable vertices : VertexPositionColor[]
    do base.Content.RootDirectory <- "Content"

    override this.Initialize() =
        base.Initialize()
        let device = base.GraphicsDevice
        let s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("effects.mgfxo")
        let reader = new BinaryReader(s)
        this.effect <- new Effect(device, reader.ReadBytes((int)reader.BaseStream.Length))
        ()

    override this.LoadContent() =
        this.vertices <-
            [|
                VertexPositionColor(Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f), Color.Red);
                VertexPositionColor(Vector3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f), Color.Green);
                VertexPositionColor(Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f), Color.Yellow)
            |]

    override this.Draw(gameTime) =
        let device = base.GraphicsDevice
        do device.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue)
        this.effect.CurrentTechnique <- this.effect.Techniques.["Pretransformed"]

        this.effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes |> Seq.iter
            (fun pass ->
                pass.Apply()
                device.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, this.vertices, 0, 1)
            )

        do base.Draw(gameTime)
```

My effect code is as follows (taken from the excellent [Riemer's tutorials](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/The_effect_file.php)) and is as simple as can be.  It's being converted as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23739155/15519), and that seems to be working because I can see the effect name if I put a breakpoint in before the draw call.

```
struct VertexToPixel
{
    float4 Position     : POSITION;    
    float4 Color        : COLOR0;
    float LightingFactor: TEXCOORD0;
    float2 TextureCoords: TEXCOORD1;
};

struct PixelToFrame
{
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

VertexToPixel PretransformedVS( float4 inPos : POSITION, float4 inColor: COLOR)
{   
    VertexToPixel Output = (VertexToPixel)0;

    Output.Position = inPos;
    Output.Color = inColor;

    return Output;    
}

PixelToFrame PretransformedPS(VertexToPixel PSIn) 
{
    PixelToFrame Output = (PixelToFrame)0;      

    Output.Color = PSIn.Color;

    return Output;
}

technique Pretransformed
{
    pass Pass0
    {   
        VertexShader = compile vs_4_0 PretransformedVS();
        PixelShader  = compile ps_4_0 PretransformedPS();
    }
}
```

It works fine if I replace the custom effect with a `BasicEffect` as per [this example](http://7sharpnine.com/posts/monogame-3d-basics/).

I'm using Monogame 3.2 and Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 3):

I worked out eventually (with help from [this forum thread](http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/402753)) that I just needed to replace `POSITION` with `SV_POSITION` in the effect file. This is a consequence of MonoGame being built in DirectX 10/11 rather then XNA's DirectX 9.